# react-gsap Tween doesn't work on component

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I use 'tween-react" to create some cool animations in my application.
I want to animate all my  components, but this won't work. Even if the  render method only returns a  tag.

But if I try to directly render a  (without a component) it works.

```
<div className="categories-wrapper">
  { categoriesDidLoad && categories.length > 0 ?
    <Tween
       staggerTo={ {x: "100px", rotation: -180} }
       stagger={0.5}
       duration={2}
       position="+=0"
     >

     // this doesn't work even if i only return a <h1> in the Categorys render method
     { categories.map( (category, index) => <Category key={ category.id } category={ category } /> ) }

     // this works perfect
     { categories.map( (category, index) => <h1>test</h1> ) }

      </Tween>

      : null
  }
</div>
```

I don't get any error or something, the animation just won't run.

Comment: Even though react-GSAP is not an official GreenSock project, you could try asking over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/forum/11-gsap/). I think you're more likely to get a response there.